# Laravel Socket without using Pusher (Laravel Broadcast Redis Socket IO) on the nginx server not working

Tags: laravel, nginx, redis, socket.io, devops

Laravel Broadcast Redis Socket IO

I have configured https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-broadcast-redis-socket-io-tutorial-example.html#google_vignette on my local but while I try to integrate on my server it is not working
Please suggest me the server configurations to change if anyone have idea

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-broadcast-redis-socket-io-tutorial-example.html#google_vignette

I am working on the nginx server
My laravel echo server is running on the
domain :staging-test.com
port: 6003

Comment: What error did you get when the socket tries to connect with a server? please elaborate on your issue with more context.

Comment: I am getting 101 status of the WS but on laravel echo server not getting any connection and event related details like Event-name ,channel name of broadcast event

Comment: If you are getting 101 status that means your client WS is connected to the server. Now open your ``Network`` in your browser debugger and then select ``WS``  from it select WS connection and see if you get anything when you broadcast something on channel.